# Create a test in JUnit4

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator, junit4

I'm trying to create a test in JUnit4 for testing this:

```
public class Task
{

public static List<Integer> withinRange(List<Integer> l, int max, int min)
{
    Iterator<Integer> it = l.iterator();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(it.hasNext())
    {
        Integer current = it.next();
        if(current < max && current >= min)
        {
            arrayList.add(current);
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
}
```

The method receives a list and two integers (only positive integers) that mark a range and returns an ArrayList that contains the elements of the list that are within the range.

How can i create a JUnit test to check if works correctly?

Comment: How would you do it "manually" (w/o JUnit)?

Comment: This seems straightforward; pass in different lists which contain set data and determine if your method produces the output you expect.  Fun questions:  what happens if the data is not sorted?  Sorted in reverse order?  Negative?  Max and min?

Comment: @Makoto - Why would sorted / unsorted matter?

Comment: @PM77-1:  Just in case the OP is interested in performance.  It shouldn't have a runtime bearing on this but you never really know until you test it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
@Test    
public void testWithinRange() {
    // Set up test data (given)
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(7);

    // perform test (when)
    List<Integer> result = Task.withinRange(list, 4, 5);

    // verify results (then)
    assertTrue(result.contains(4));
    assertTrue(result.contains(5));
    assertFalse(result.contains(7));
}
```

The basics of a test is to set up your test data, call the test, and then verify the results.

Then vary it with different parameters to check it still works in different situations. For example, what happens when the list is null, or empty? What happens when the range has a negative number, or the max is lower than the min?